# Is it possible to sign a server certificate with longer key length than that of CA certificate

Tags: ssl, certificate

I have a self signed CA which has 1024 bit key length. Is it possible to sign a server certificate with longer key length (2048 bit) using this CA? I want to sign a server certificate and configure that for Active Directory service.

I'm able to do this using bouncy castle. My concern is about 
1) Is this a good idea?
2) How would the certificate trust be established? Would that be okay.

Comment: RSA 1024 bit keys should not be used anymore especially for a CA. If you can create a new CA with RSA2048 bit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use your 1024-bit RSA private key to sign a certificate for a server that is using a 2048-bit key. The length, and even the type, of the key in the certificate you're signing (the server's certificate) has no relation to the key you're using to do the signing. For example, you could have your 1024-bit RSA private key sign a certificate for a server using a 256-bit EC key if you wanted.

(Technically, you aren't signing the certificate itself, but a hash of the certificate. See [this question and answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9896/how-does-rsa-signature-verification-work) for details. But conceptually, you can think of it as "signing the certificate".)

Trust is established the same as with any other certificate chain:

1. Your client contains your CA's 1024-bit public key in its trust store.
2. Your client connects to a server, which sends its certificate, signed by your CA.
3. Your client sees that the certificate is signed by a CA in your trust store, so it verifies the CA's signature on the server's certificate using the CA's public key in the client's trust store.
4. The signature matches, so the client trusts the server's certificate.